# Using Multiple Stencils in Blender Game Engine

Tags: texturing, game-engine, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to texture a large landscape for the Game Engine using several layers of stencils. It looks great in the preview window but when I go to play the game, the texture doesn't show up properly. It's like the stencil is repeating itself over the surface. I double checked the UV's and they are laid out properly. Has anyone else encountered this problem or knows how to fix it? Pictures attached.

[image: Preview]
[image: In Game]
[image: Properties]